# Submit Array type input file in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a form, which has two fields: "product_name" and "product_q" and in my form i have an option to increase the number of fields in `product_name` and `product_q`

```
 <select name="product_name[]" id="product_name">
 <option value="please select"></option> 
 <option value="1">demo1</option> 
 <option value="2">demo2</option> 

 </select>

<select name="product_q[]" id="product_q">
 <option value="please select"></option> 
 <option value="1">1</option> 
 <option value="2">2</option> 

 </select>
```

and an action page like

```
 public function order(){


    $Product_q = $this->input->post('quantity');
    $sponserid = $this->session->userdata('number');
    $pname['product_name'] = $this->input->post('product_name');
    foreach($Product_q as $key => $value){
    $data['Product_q'] = $value;
    $data['Product_Name'] = $pname['product_name'][$key]; 
    $this->mymodel->insert_items($data);

    }
```

and my model

```
function insert_items($data){
    $this->db->insert("lucky_order", $data);
    return;

}
```

Please help to insert data database my form look like this:

**FORM with one field**
[image: FORM with one field]

**Form with two field**
[image: form with two field]

Comment: `<select name="product_name[]" id="product_name">` **this is not multiple** so you get one value  only

Comment: please check sir image

Comment: in image have add more option which use to increase the number of field both product_name and product_q

Comment: what issue are you experiencing? and what debugging steps have you taken already?

Comment: insert product_q right but at palce name insert number like 1 and also insert only one data

Comment: according to your screenshot you've one dropdown for selecting a member, one dropdown for selecting a product and one input field for the quantity - but you post 2 select dropdowns for your product and the quantity - that doesn fit; you should post your html code and the javascript code aswell because i think there is something fundamentally wrong with your understanding how a html form works...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
<select name="product_name[]" class="product_name">
 <option value="please select"></option> 
 <option value="1">demo1</option> 
 <option value="2">demo2</option> 

 </select>

<select name="product_q[]" class="product_q">
 <option value="please select"></option> 
 <option value="1">1</option> 
 <option value="2">2</option> 

 </select> 
<input type="hidden" name="product_count" value="1" />



You have to increment /decrement the product_count value on addition 
or removal or product
```

for controller :

```
 loop your function in model for inserting into database
```

for times of product_count 
and the values for each using $key
 something like this :

```
        for ($i=0; $i<$_POST['product_count']; $i++){
```

call the function of insert by passing the each value using above $i variable.
    like

```
         $_POST['product_name'][$i]; 

this will get you your first product name similarly for all 
   and you can call the model function and pass the above values each 
time with incremented value of $i
```

Comment: but in codeigniter $_POST['product_name'][$i];  how to write in form of $this->input->post['product_name']; please suggest

Comment: you can try this  : 
$product_q = $this->input->post('product_q');

$data = array();
foreach($this->input->post['product_name'] as $key=>$val)
{
 $data[]=array('product_name'=>$val,'product_q'=>$product_q[$key]);
}

here you have created data array for all products and now may be you can try for bulk insert method to insert your data.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot insert array directly into database so before inserting it to database we need to encode array into json. You can do it by following `<?php json_encode($data); ?>`
and then later where you want fetch this data then you can simply decode that data back to array by using following method `<?php json_decode($data); ?>`

Comment: Hi,
I really sorry my answer was not worked for you maybe it wasted your time but its fault I thought you are having problem in only insertion and else is working so that's why I have answered this.